# what is the meaning of "strange pub"?

Tags: vocabulary, british-english

"You cannot order it in a strange pub..." I found this when I was solving a crossword.. I'm wondering what dose the "strange pub" mean?

According to the dictionary.com the "pub" is a British slang means "bar".But "strange pub" means "strange bar"??? not making sense...

In the crossword the answer is a two word phrase ... first one is a 3 letter word and the second is a 5 letter.

Comment: Strange could mean unfamiliar.  How many letters?  Could it be "usual", as in you can't order your "usual" in a strange pub?

Comment: It isn't intended to mean anything.  As a crossword clue, "strange" is a hint that the answer is an anagram.

Comment: @Ste Bingo: "the usual"

Comment: Sometimes I impress even myself...  ;o)

Comment: It's a crossword.  The clues are supposed to be confusing.

Comment: "Pub" is actually a contraction of "Public House", a place where alcoholic drinks are available.  Many establishments may have a 'bar' without being a pub.

Comment: @TrevorD: what's your point? Cryptic crossword clues often clue "bar" with "pub" or vice versa.

Comment: @ColinFine  OP had suggested that "*pub* is British slang for *bar*". I was merely explaining the meaning/derivation of "pub", and that it is not necessarily synonymous with "bar".

Comment: @TrevorD: Oh, right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the strange British pastime of [cryptic crosswords](http://www.wikihow.com/Solve-a-Cryptic-Crossword), words are often used in deliberately misleading ways, to create the puzzle. Nearly always if there is an apparently meaningless phrase in a crossword clue, it is indeed a completely meaningless phrase, and the words in it need to be taken in a different way (using different meanings of the original words, or just the letters of the word).

However, now that you have given the length of the answer, it is obvious to me that the words do have their usual meaning, and it is talking about an unfamiliar pub. The whole clue is a pun, based on the literal meaning and the very specialised British cultural meaning of the two-word phrase which is the answer.

Comment: However, the crossword that I mentioned in my question is a crossword from The Guardian, from its quiptic category.

Comment: The Guardian's "Quiptic" are crpytic crosswords, but simpler ones than their main Cryptic.

Comment: I think there is a dual purpose to the use of 'strange' in this clue, ultimately it means a pub the orderer isn't familiar with, but in looking for possible meanings one is likely to consider *unusual* which takes you an additional step towards the answer.